# Can anyone tell me how to play ps3 games on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, ps3

I have just started using ubuntu 12.04 and i was wondering whether i can play ps2 or ps3 games on ubuntu.

Please help if its possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this myself but I think it's worth checking out the following links:

[pcsx2](http://pcsx2.net/)

[sixaxis](http://www.ps3hax.net/2011/05/sixaxis-emulator-play-ps3-games-with-keyboard-and-mouse/)

For ps2 and ps3, respectively. To be honest, it will work but it will not work as well as simply using the respective game consoles.

Comment: well i hope it works. But its worth trying..